# BitmapImage: How do I wait for BitmapImage to be initialized before returning image? (C# .NET)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmapimage

I have a method which opens an image from within a zip file, and returns that image as a BitmapImage.

```
public BitmapImage GetImageFromSource()
{
    using (System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive zi = System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open(ZipFileLocation, System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
        using (Stream source = zi.GetEntry(InternalLocation).Open())
        {
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            img.BeginInit();
            img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            img.StreamSource = source;
            img.EndInit();

            //sleeping here allows img to complete initialization
            //not sleeping here means img is still blank upon return
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

            return img;
        }
    }
}
```

The zip file contains a mixture of large and small images. If the image is large, img may not have completed initialization before the program reaches the return. If this happens, the method returns a blank BitmapImage.

If I Sleep before returning, the method works, and with a sufficient delay, large images are successfully initialized.

Sleep isn't ideal, as it slows down the program by unnecessarily locking the main thread. How can I get the method to wait for initialization to complete before returning the BitmapImage?

I have tried IsDownloading and the DownloadCompleted event. IsDownloading is always set to 'true', and DownloadCompleted never seems to be triggered.

Comment: Does the [`DownloadCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event fire perhaps?

Comment: It's strange - only sometimes. It does fire, but only when img has already been given the time to finish initializing (such as by using Sleep).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really good practice to lock the main thread waiting for the bitmap to load, the framework may need to defer the load for some reason. That is in fact what's happening here, and when the load does actually occur you've already disposed of the file variables. You can return an image straight away but you should defer the disposing of those variables until after the file has loaded:

```
public BitmapImage GetImageFromSource()
{
    System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive zi = System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open(ZipFileLocation, System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode.Read);
    Stream source = zi.GetEntry(InternalLocation).Open();

    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
    img.DownloadCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        source.Dispose();
        zi.Dispose();
    };

    img.BeginInit();
    img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    img.StreamSource = source;
    img.EndInit();

    return img;
}
```